# Find .exe file for entry in Windows 10 "Starup Apps" settings

Tags: windows, startup

I have a couple suspicious mystery entries in my Startup Apps. MalwareBytes didn't flag them but I want to try them on VirusTotal to be sure.

[image]
[image]

*startup entries named just named "Program" and "Update" that just look like the sort of thing a crypto miner virus would hide itself as*

[A quick google search](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd) says to look in `shell:startup`, which expands to `C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` but there's nothing there.

UPDATE before i even submitted the question I thought to look in the startup tab in task manager, right-click, and select "open file location". the "Update" one turns out to be related to Electron. but "Program" has that option greyed out so question still stands. where do I find the `.exe`?

Comment: Autoruns will usually show these.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the following registry keys and see if you spot anything unusual or uninstalled there:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

If you do, don't simply delete the registry key, and instead try to fully remove the application in question.

It's unlikely that either of those are malware, but instead just badly made applications that haven't cleanly uninstalled, or haven't named their startup object correctly.